# Batch how to move hidden directories?

Tags: batch-file, directory, move

I am using the following script lines in a batch script (.bat) to copy the contents of a directory (foo) to another (bar):

```
move "C:\foo\*.*" "C:\bar\"
for /d %%a in ("C:\foo\*") do move "%%~fa" "C:\bar\"
```

The first line moves files and the second lines moves folders. However, these aren't moving the hidden directories. `.git` is a common example. I tried `for /d %%a in ("C:\foo\.*") do move "%%~fa" "C:\bar\"` with no success.

How can I move my hidden directories along with the rest of my files and directories?

EDIT: The following solution is very close to doing what is required, but fails because the "move" command can't find the hidden folder (tried the same on a .folder that wasn't hidden and it worked):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /a:hd "C:\foo\*"') do move "C:\foo\%%G" "C:\bar\"
```

Comment: `.*.*`. The part after the LAST `.` are extensions. Previous `.` are just part of the file name. So Files starting with `.` then any text including `.` until the last `.` then any extension. A `*` by itself is assumed to mean `*.*` (an MSDos compat thing) but not everywhere. Use the correct form `*.*`.

Comment: You can try using `attrib -h *.*` to remove the hidden attribute

Comment: @Mark fixed, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some extra research, I found that robocopy seems to be included by default in Windows 10 distributions and `robocopy /MOVE` allows moving all the needed files and folders in a single line, such as:

```
robocopy "C:\foo" "C:\bar" /E /MOVE
```

Additional logging options can be added to reduce the output to the command line.

Comment: That should more correctly be `%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe "C:\foo" "C:\bar" /E /Move`. Directories do not have trailing backslashes, a backslash is a path separator, as you're not separating a path, you don't need it, _(and therefore don't need to escape each of them in order that the doublequotes aren't in turn escaped)_.

Comment: @Compo Correct, I am editing the answer accordingly

Comment: There's no need to stipulate `*.*` either, _(hence the reason I didn't in my previous comment)_, if you read the [tag:RoboCopy] usage information, `help robocopy`, you'll clearly see that the `default is "*.*"`.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do, you can first use the `attrib` command before moving things to remove hidden attributes from files. You can use this to accomplish your goal:

```bat
attrib -h "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\tmp\*.*"
move "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\tmp\*.*" "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\"
```

To do this with other things, you can do this:

```bat
attrib -h "<SourceParentFolder>\*.*"
move <source> <destination>
```

**NOTES**: You should note @Mark's comment. Using `C:\file\path\folder\*` is not correct. You should use `C:\file\path\folder\*.*`. For more information view [@Mark's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61901494/batch-how-to-move-dot-directories-hidden-directories#comment109486586_61901494)

For more information on `attrib` use `attrib /?` or check [this](https://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html)

Comment: What if I don't want to remove the hidden attribute? I wish to simply move the file, unaltered..

Comment: You would have to edit specific files attributes. To add back the hidden attribute use `attrib +h <file>`

Comment: But then the script becomes far more complicated if I don't know in advance which files/folders should be hidden and which shouldn't... There would need to be variables involed to remember which files/folders were hidden before the moving, and more operations. This is too complicated for what I am looking for, I have found a better solution and will post it in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

A file or directory name beginning with `.` does not mean that it is hidden.

Anyway, [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)/[`for /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) iterates over non-hidden files/directories. However, [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) allows to return hidden items as well when using its `/A` option, which can be made use of by using [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html):

```cmd
rem // Change into source directory:
pushd "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\tmp" && (
    rem // Iterate over all directories, even hidden and system ones:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('dir /B /A:D-S-L ".*"') do (
        rem // Actually move the directory:
        move "%%I" "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\"
    )
    rem // Return from source directory:
    popd
)
```

Comment: This is very close to the solution but does not work. I still get "The system cannot find the file specified" which is the same thing I get if I do the following: ```for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /a:hd "C:\foo\*"') do move "C:\foo\%%G" "C:\bar\"```. This is likely due to the fact that the folder is hidden.

Comment: @DCD, the options you've used with `dir` selects all files, _(yes a directory is a technically still a file)_, which have the hidden and directory attributes, it does not exclude those which, for instance, have system reparse attributes. So the first thing I'd suggest is to change it to `Dir /B /A:DH-S-L` to ensure that you're not trying to move files with those attributes. In addition to that, we have no idea whether the person executing the script has sufficient permissions to move the directory, or one or more files which it may contain, so that could also be a factor.

Comment: @Compo I am unfamiliar with system reparse attributes, but seeing as my goal here is to move a hidden directory to another location, I don't know if this really has to be taken into account or not. I am having the issue by simply creating a new folder and adding the hidden flag to it and running the script as administrator, so it is definitely a hidden issue and not another. I have found and posted a simpler solution.

Comment: @DCD, instead of creating a directory, adding a hidden attribute to it, then moving it, why don't you just create it in the location you require, and add the hidden attribute? Regardless, those factors did not form part of your question, if you want assistance with a specific issue, not a generic one, you should have edited your question to include that information, which in this case, should've included the rest of the script content. Now, that you've received answers, you should ask the responders if they'll be happy for you to change the question. Otherwise you should submit a new one.

Comment: @Compo, it's a good idea to exclude system files and reparse points, though I wouldn't add the hidden attribute in order to move non-hidden directories too (although I might have misinterpreted the OP's intention)...

Comment: I uderstand what you're saying @aschipfl, my response was to their commented command, `dir /b /a:hd "C:\foo\*"`, not to the main question.

Comment: @Compo I think you misunderstood my comment. The directory creation part was about testing the script, not part of the script. My question remains solely about moving a hidden directory, which is not possible with the ```move``` command, and the proposed solutions offre some alternatives. The notion of system reparse attributes is beyond my knowledge, and seem part of a non-generic answer imo.

Comment: @DCD, I fully understood your comment, I simply added to it, to ensure that any hidden directory you were trying to move, did not also carry a system or reparse attribute too. _(Think of the reparse attribute as a junction or symlink)_. All I was trying to do was to reduce the chances of the `move` command failing for you, _(there's a greater chance of a file object which has a system attribute of running into issues than one which is simply hidden)_.